# Gradle error: "Cannot calculate intersection of exclude rules"

Tags: gradle

We are exploring upgrading from Gradle 2.2.1 to Gradle 2.10. However when we compile, we get the error "Cannot calculate intersection of exclude rules":

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myProject:compile'.
>   > Cannot calculate intersection of exclude rules: {module servlet-api}, {UnionSpec {ExcludeRuleBackedSpec {module servlet-api} {module AlphaLib} {module ant}} {ExcludeRuleBackedSpec {module servlet-api} {
>   module ant} {exclude-rule *:*:ant-(.*)?.* with matcher regexp}}}

We're really not sure what to make of this. The part of the `build.gradle` file that refers to these modules are as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.example:AlphaLib:dev') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache'
        exclude module: 'OtherLibrary'
        force = true
        changing = true
    }
    compile ('com.example:BetaLib:1.0') {
        // Exclude AlphaLib and rely on the above declaration
        // Otherwise Gradle will pull in the dependencies we want to exclude from it
        exclude module: 'AlphaLib' 
        force = true
        changing = true
    }
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
}
```

Admittedly, we have a strange workaround with excluding AlphaLib's specific libraries, but I don't know if that's the source of the problems. Again, this worked fine in Gradle 2.2.1, but not in Gradle 2.10.

So how can we solve Gradle's "Cannot calculate intersection of exclude rules" error?